# Determine Superabundance

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, decision-problem, factoring

A [superabundant number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superabundant_number) is an integer *n* that sets a new upper bound for its ratio with the [divisor sum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) σ. In other words, *n* is superabundant if and only if, for all positive integers *x* that are less than *n*:

$$\frac{\sigma(n)}n>\frac{\sigma(x)}x$$

For a few of the values:

```
n   σ(n)   σ(n)/n   superabundant
1   1      1.0000   yes
2   3      1.5000   yes
3   4      1.3333   no
4   7      1.7500   yes
5   6      1.2000   no
6   12     2.0000   yes
7   8      1.1429   no
8   15     1.8750   no
9   13     1.4444   no
```

A longer list of these (for test cases) can be found at [OEIS A004394](https://oeis.org/A004394).

One *highly recommended* negative test case (if your interpreter can handle it) is 360360, because it ties with the last superabundant number.

## Challenge

Your program should take in a single positive integer, and output a truthy or falsey value representing whether that integer is superabundant.

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Æs÷$ÞṪ=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9qZWxsef//w4Zzw7ckw57huao9/zEwMMK1LMOHJGrigJwgLT4g4oCdwrXigqxZ/w)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
Æs÷$ÐṀ⁼W
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW/Hh7SqHJzzc2fCocU/4////jUwA)

[Test Suite!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9qZWxsef//w4Zzw7ckw5DhuYDigbxX/zEwMMK1LMOHJGrigJwgLT4g4oCdwrXigqxZ/w)

#### Explanation

```
Æs÷$ÐṀ⁼W ~ Full program (monadic).

    ÐṀ   ~ Keep the elements with maximal link value (auto-rangifies).
Æs       ~ Divisor sum.
  ÷$     ~ Divide by the current element.
      ⁼W ~ Check equality with the input wrapped into a singleton.
         ~ (for integers like 360360)
```

Comment: I think you can do [`Æs÷$ÐṀ=`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW/Hh7SqHJzzc2WD7P@jonqDD7Y@a1qh4Awn3//@NTAA) for 7 bytes. I didn't realize `ÐṀ` rangified, that is useful to know.

Comment: @dylnan No I can't. Although it cannot be tested online, it fails for `360360`. In fact, this was [my initial version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/151187/1)

Comment: Why would it fail for `360360`?

Comment: @dylnan `360360` is the *first* number it would fail for (I think), because it is the first number to tie a result which occurred before. (and our result would be `[0, 1]`)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I see, thanks

Comment: Does jelly have a builtin for stable sorting?

Comment: @StephenLeppik Not sure what you are talking about. Example? >_>

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder you could sort the numbers from 1 to x by divisor sum ratio and check if x is the first element.

Comment: @StephenLeppik There's `Þ`, but that would definitely end up being longer AFAIK.

Comment: Stephen is close, but it turns out to still be 8 bytes: `RÆs÷$ÞṪ=` due to `Þ` not casting to range.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 73 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder. -7 bytes thanks to Laikoni.*

```hs
r=read.show
s n=sum[r i|i<-[1..n],n`mod`i<1]/r n
f n=all((s n>=).s)[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxDkAwEADQvV9xg4GEE4tJ/YhINEFctFe5Ixb/XhJvfpvTffE@JbGyuBl1i7dRYKtXGATooa4aGkQeS55CnCfqmrEWYLN@yXmf59/ubYFa/C8FRwwWDiE@IYMV2vQC)

Haskell's type system isn't very golfy...

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>64</s> <s>63</s> 61 bytes

**-1** byte thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder).

**-2** bytes thanks to [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn).

```hs
a!x=a*sum[y|y<-[1..x],mod x y<1]
f n=and[x!n>n!x|x<-[1..n-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBCoMwEAXQfU/xA11JlWRveoOeIAxlQIOhyVTUwgS8e0rpW7@F99ecc2ts1HO3f0qoZx374IZB6VbeExR1dHSJEM8yBTVyF6On/pP0jqgVTgKPwuvjiXVLcuCKmPIxb4j4PWetpfYF)

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 41 bytes

```matlab
@(n)([~,p]=max((x=1:n)*~mod(x,x')./x))==n
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI09TI7pOpyDWNjexQkOjwtbQKk9Tqy43P0WjQqdCXVNPv0JT09Y2739afpFCHlDWkksBCNKA@rhS81L@AwA)

#### Explanation

```matlab
@(n)                                       % Define anonymous function of n
                x=1:n                      % Range from 1 to n. Call that x
                        mod(x,x')          % n×n matrix of all pair-wise moduli
                       ~                   % Logical negate. True means it's a divisor
               (     )*                    % Matrix-multiply x times the above matrix
                                           % (gives the dot product of vector x times
                                           % each column of the matrix)
                                 ./x       % Divide each column by each entry in x
     [~,p]=max(                     )      % Index of first occurrence of maximum
    (                                )==n  % Does it equal n?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
LÑOā/ZQ¨_P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f5/BE/yON@lGBh1bEB/z/bwYA)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W/pU1b53@fwRP8jjfpRgYdWxAf8r1Q6vN9K4fB@JR3NmP8A)

**Explanation**

```
L            # push range [1 ... input]
 Ñ           # divisors of each
  O          # sum of each
   ā/        # divide each by its 1-based index
     Z       # get max
      Q      # compare to each
       ¨     # remove the last element
        _    # logical negation
         P   # product
```

Comment: I *think* (though I ain't sure) this fails for `360360` (see the challenge for more details: *One highly recommended negative test case is 360360, because it ties with the last superabundant number.*).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: True. Fixed it, but there may be a better way to do this now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 14 bytes

<sup><sub>([FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman) saved 1 byte)</sub></sup>

```
qh.Mcs*M{yPZZS
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qh.Mcs%2aM%7ByPZZS&input=20&test_suite=0&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A20%0A24&debug=0)** or **[see more test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qh.Mcs%2aM%7ByPZZS&input=20&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A20%0A24&debug=0)**

Just my mandatory Pyth submission which is most likely golfable.

#### How?

```
qh.Mcs*M{yPZZS ~ Full program. Q = input.

             S ~ The integers in the range [1, Q].
  .M           ~ Get the elements with maximal function value.
    cs*M{yPZZ  ~ Key function: uses a variable Z.
         yPZ      ~ The powerset of the prime factors of Z.
        {         ~ Deduplicated.
      *M          ~ Product of each.
     s            ~ And summed.
    c       Z     ~ Divided by Z.
 h             ~ First element.
q              ~ Check equality with the input. Outputs either True or False.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 77 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Rod. -3 bytes thanks to Dennis.*

```python
lambda n:max(range(1,n+1),key=lambda k:sum((k%i<1)/i for i in range(1,k)))==n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctBCoAgEADAr@wl2CUhJOgg@ZMuRlmLuYUV5OvtUudhjnytu7TF26FsLo6TAzHRPZicLDNqJbUmFeZsPw3mvCNiqLjX1DD4PQEDC/whEJG1Uo7EcqHHjqi8)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 35 bytes

Thanks to Mr.Xcoder for finding the problem and to cole for fixing it!

```
[:([:*/{:>}:)@(%~>:@#.~/.~&.q:)1+i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYc7CoAwEAX7nOKh@InKukaIsKB4D0vx24i1mKtHm8AMzJx@6wWMXz9JPklRPzK8osc8cYOMMbmaXEq36KY8yGsVEbK1pwwVXsGm1DLvF1bYEI2xjDCm6wxzuNbyj/8A)

Comment: This fails for `360360` (see the challenge for more details: *One highly recommended negative test case is 360360, because it ties with the last superabundant number.*).

Comment: Fixed for +3 bytes. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##NYc7CoAwEAX7nOKh@InKukaIsKB4D0vx24i1mKtHm8AMzJx@6wWMXz9JPklRPzK8osc8cYOMMbmaXEq36KY8yGsVEbK1pwwVXsGm1DLvF1bYEI2xjDCm6wxzuNbyj/8A). Working on golfing. I like the use of `#.~` a lot (honestly the whole divisor sum function is really nice). What was wrong btw is that, though the thought of doing `{:=>./` is clever, it doesn't satisfy the "greater than" part of the question.

Comment: Here's what I came up with to replace the sigma function, which is at the same length currently: `(1#.{:(]*0=|~)])\ `. Something's wrong with it though, maybe you have some thoughts?

Comment: @cole The credits for the sum of divisors function go to Roger Hui, in [this essay](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Essays/Divisors) . 
I also started writing another sigma function but stopped after I reached 9 bytes and decided it won't be shorter than the one with the prime factorization.
Thanks for fixing the problem!

Comment: @cole The shortest other verb for sum of divisors I came up with is this: `(1#.]*0=|~)1+i.`
It's a hook and don't fit as easily into place though :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 52 bytes

```
n->indmax(sum(x for x=1:m if m%x<1)//m for m=1:n)==n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchBCoMwEAXQvaf4iIWZRZFshErjXQQNjDi/ohVy@9S6fG85Vxu7kmLhczBOPmY5TpeM9NmRY@gdluCP/A7atn63X02NkeUvwojQvypg243flVI3RCNJqFprNXMqPw)

This solution uses rational numbers to ensure correctness in case of equality. 
(Testing 360360 took almost 10 minutes.)

Using floating point, 2 bytes can be saved with the left divide:

```
n->indmax(m\sum(x for x=1:m if m%x<1)for m=1:n)==n
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>53</s> 50 bytes

```
a=Tr@Divisors@#/#&;AllTrue[a@#-Array[a,#-1],#>0&]&
```

Pure function. Takes an integer as input and returns `True` or `False` as output.

Comment: Would something like `Tr@Divisors@#` works?

Answer (score 2):

## R using `numbers`, 59 bytes

```
f=function(n)which.max(sapply(1:n,numbers::Sigma)/(1:n))==n
```

Answer (score 1):

## Japt v2.0a0, <s>12</s> 16 bytes

Sleep deprived brain can't seem to improve on this any further!

Returns `1` for truthy or `0` for falsey.

```
Æâ x÷U >Xâ x÷XÃ×
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=xuIgePdVID5Y4iB491jD1w==&input=OA==)

Sacrificed 4 bytes to handle `360360`.

---

### Explanation

- Implicit input of integer `U`.
- `Æ Ã` creates an array of integers from `0` to `U-1` and passes each through the following function as `X`.
- `â` gets the divisors of `U`.
- `÷U` divides each of those by `U`.
- `x` sums the results.
- `Xâ` gets the divisors of `X`.
- `÷X` divides each of those by `X`.
- `x` sums the results.
- `>` checks if the first result is greater than the second.
- `×` reduces the resulting array of booleans by multiplcation.

Comment: If your current approach matches your explanation, it fails for `360360` or other such integers: *One highly recommended negative test case (if your interpreter can handle it) is 360360, because it ties with the last superabundant number*

Comment: @Mr.XCoder: Nuts, you're right! That's probably gonna cost me some bytes when I get a moment to fix it.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: Fixed for now, will have to come back later to see if I can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 33 bytes

```apl
{⍵=⊃⌽+⌿∘.≤⍨((+/⍳(/⍨)0=⍳|⊢)÷⊢)¨⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR71bbR91NT/q2av9qGf/o44Zeo86lzzqXaGhoa3/qHezBpBYoWlgC2TWPOpapHl4O4g8tALIB@qs/f8/XwGkQiFN4dAKhXwFoIkKQCkLEwMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
εü<m§ṁ/Ḋṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUQAu/9odXNr/yBtKHPigoFyKcK2/861w7w8bcKn4bmBL@G4iuG5q////zEKMgozCjQKNQo2CjcKOAo5CjEwCjYwCjgwCjM2MA)
Too slow for the 360360 test case.

### Explanation

```
εü<m§ṁ/Ḋṫ  Implicit input, say n=6.
        ṫ  Decreasing range: [6,5,4,3,2,1]
   m       Map this function (example argument k=4):
       Ḋ    Divisors of k: [1,2,4]
    §ṁ      Map and sum
      /     division by k: 7/4
           Result: [2,6/5,7/4,4/3,3/2,1]
 ü         Remove duplicates by
  <        strict comparison. This greedily extracts a non-decreasing subsequence: [2]
ε          Is it a singleton list? Yes.
```

Comment: I got [`£ü¤<§ṁ/ḊN`](https://tio.run/##AUMAvP9odXNr/yBtKHPigoFyKcK2/8Kjw7zCpDzCp@G5gS/huIpO////MQoyCjMKNAo1CjYKNwo4CjkKMTAKNjAKODAKMzYw). Creating the entire list of superabundant numbers

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 37 bytes

```
 ↑1=⍒⌽(+/¨((0=(⍳¨n)|¨n)×⍳¨n)~¨⊂0)÷n←⍳⎕
```

Prompts for screen input.

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), 99 bytes

```
s(n,j,k){for(j=k=0;j++<n;)k+=n%j?0:j;n=k;}f(n,i,r){for(i=r=0;++i<n;)r=1.*s(n)/n<1.*s(i)/i?:r;r=!r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7BDoJADETvfEUlIdm6q8CV0vAjXgwEs0uspnojfPtacE7NzJtJx8tjHHP@OAkpLLjOL3WJF24oed8L4eJZqjQ0XSLhhbbZyBj0T0ZWI72PO6ncXs82hLX0xxWxjkOnpHxS2nKULzzvURwWawEmWwC3u8ItgZUaAu8Fj3DXWy2dXVlNHVTTTcoAEsA@QKRiyz8)

## C, 108 bytes

```
float s(n,j,k){for(j=k=0;j++<n;)k+=n%j?0:j;return k;}f(n,i,r){for(i=r=0;++i<n;)s(n)/n<s(i)/i&&++r;return!r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BDoIwEETvfMVKAulma4CrS@OPeCFgTVtcTMET4duxqHOceTPTn/uxk8e@23HqFpiVaK8DrnaKyptgavZErTAGMlL4a33xHO/LOwoE3mzCnY4/3JmYcCJ34GkIK2ln5bByZUkU/7VT5G13ssCzc6IwWzNISn1QhyumYZC2qRmIBL/hoVdMqVV5MVygGG6SaxAN6R@Rs23/AA)

Comment: So, why does `s` need to return a float?

Comment: @StephenLeppik To use float division instead of integer division when comparing `s(n)/n` to `s(i)/i`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), <s>120</s> 118 bytes

```swift
let s={n in Float((1...n).reduce(0){n%$1>0 ?$0:$0+$1})}
{n in(1..<n).reduce(0){max($0,s($1)/Float($1))}<s(n)/Float(n)}
```

Takes some time (around 6 seconds on TIO) to compile because of the implicit type declarations in Swift.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc3BCsIwEATQu1@xlAi7WGMCnmqtN/8jaAKBui1JRKHk26OhePA2DLyZ@PIuHUsZbYJ4Xhg8w3WcTELUUkomGez9ebOoaOGt0IOCi1CdUDuhM@VNdW51FfR/4GHeKFQbUWg6rKvfRLmPyL@CKRc3BfD1uV5qtczBc0LfOvTURjubYNIUugb2AzR0yuUD)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
RÆs©Ṫ×R>®×$Ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//UsOGc8Kp4bmqw5dSPsKuw5ck4bqg////MTIw) or [Find all superabundant numbers below 1000.](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//UsOGc8Kp4bmqw5dSPsKuw5ck4bqg/8i3w4fDkGb/)

because I hate floating points.

Answer (score 0):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 79 bytes

```
d=n=>fors=i=0i<=n i++s+=i*!n%i
f=n=>{forc=1c<n c++if(d(n)/n)<=d(c)/c return0 1}
```

### Explained

This first defines the function `d` which is the `σ` function, and this is the golfed version of

```javascript
function d(n){
    var s = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(n%i == 0){
            s += i;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

We can set i to 0, because `i*n%0` will always equal `0*...`, thus `0`.

The next half of this defines the function `f`, which is the Superabandunce function, and it is just the golfed form of

```javascript
function f(n){
    for(var c=1; c<n; c++){
        if( (d(n)/n) <= (d(c)/c) ){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And this just checks, as the challenge spec suggests, that all integers from 1 to n-1 have a `d(n)/n` of less than the input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrBCsIwDADQs/2KOBBaM1h7b/wSL5JaSIUoXTeQsW@v8/xeXvT17T2R0i2/60xCXiIpCOKMJNezXsTkP2@HMwWOCowo2SarblIXKVl2E0N9tqWqh7D3o8L6qFAoQInBQ0HczOlTRZstIwz3NoyQbXHO7P0H)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 84 bytes

```
say!grep$a[-1]<=$a[$_],0..(@a=map{$i=$_;my$j;map{$i%$_ or$j+=$_/$i}1..$i;$j}1..<>)-2
```

requires `-E` (free)

a straightforward implementation of the specification, golfed

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 61 chars, 122 bytes

```
r←f w;m;k
r←m←0
r+←1⋄k←r÷⍨11πr⋄→3×⍳r≥w⋄→2×⍳∼m<k⋄m←k⋄→2
r←k>m
```

11π is the function sum of factors

```
  (⍳9),¨ f¨1..9
1 1  2 1  3 0  4 1  5 0  6 1  7 0  8 0  9 0 
  f 360360
0
```